# What software to use to make games for free with commercial use?

Tags: 2d, browser-based-games

I am going to make a 2D game, I need free software for my team of five or less people. I should be able to sell in-game currency but the game will be free. The software should be able to compile the game for a windows, linux(debian), Mac, Android and IOS. I have windows and dont want software which needs .net framework or sort of. I need something similar to visual basic but for commercial uses by an organisation. I also will need software for creating open-source server which users can download and monetize themselves(selling stuff or currency in their server).
Edit: it will be in-brouser game with node-js but still thanks.

Comment: Questions about "how to get started," "what to learn next," or "which technology to use" are discussion-oriented questions which involve answers that are either based on opinion, or which are all equally valid. Those kinds of questions are outside the scope of this site. Visit our [help center](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help) for more information.

Comment: +user000user I know and checker help center but still don't know where to post opinion-based questions.

Comment: @MaximumOfEnter The last section of the [help center's *What topics can I ask about here?* page](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) has a list of sites that welcome open-ended questions. Even more options in [this meta post](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/1840/7804).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to your requirement you should go through Unity (Game Engine) and you can feature it with Visual Studio Tools.

As Unity has Free version as well as Licensed Version but you can develop your game in free version as well.
And you will able to compile the game for so many platform as you mentioned in your question.
So best luck :)

Answer (score 0):

MonoGame meets all of your requirements: http://www.monogame.net/

Unity free edition does as well, though if your organization makes more than $100,000 a year, you can no longer use unity without paying.